# Error integration jsf +spring +hibernate +managedbean

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf, managed-bean

I have web application wich uses jsf 2.0 and spring 3.0 +hibernate 4 The problem is that: jsf managed beans can't use spring beans using dependency injection There are my config files:

Rq When I change Mybean like that @ManagedBean(name="userMB")
@RequestScoped
and I put @ManagedProperty(value="#{Service}") it is recognized on jsf page but there is error

```
package com.ardia.service;
import java.util.List;
import com.ardia.model.Composant;

public interface ComposantService {

    void inserComposant(Composant comp);

    Composant getComposantById(int compId);

    Composant getComposant(String compname);

    List<Composant> getComposants();

}
```

this is my service

```
package com.ardia.service;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import com.ardia.model.Composant;

@Service("compService")
@Transactional
public class ComposantImp implements ComposantService {


    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    @Override
    public void inserComposant(Composant comp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(comp);
    }

    @Override
    public Composant getComposantById(int compId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return (Composant) sessionFactory.
                  getCurrentSession().
                  get(Composant.class, compId);
    }

    @Override
    public Composant getComposant(String compname) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Composant> getComposants() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.
                  getCurrentSession().
                  createCriteria(Composant.class);
                return criteria.list();
    }

}
```

This is My Managed Bean

```
package ardia.beans;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import com.ardia.model.Composant;
import com.ardia.service.ComposantService;

@Component("compBean")
@Scope("session")
public class CoposantBean implements Serializable{

@Autowired
private ComposantService service;

private List<Composant> list;

@PostConstruct
public void init()
{
    list=service.getComposants();

}

public List<Composant> getList() {
    return list;
}

public void setList(List<Composant> list) {
    this.list = list;
}
}
```

this is My application context spring

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">


   <context:component-scan 
    base-package="ardia.beans" />
  <context:component-scan 
    base-package="com.ardia.service" />
<!-- Data Source Declaration -->
    <bean id="DataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" >
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql:PFE" />
        <property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />

    </bean>

    <!-- Session Factory Declaration -->
    <bean id="SessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="DataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.ardia.model" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>


    </bean>

 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

 <bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" >
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory"/>
  </bean>


</beans>
```

this web.xml and facec.conf.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd">
 <application>
  <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
 </application>
</faces-config>
```

faces config

```
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
 <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>classpath:application.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
  <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
  <param-value>default</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
  <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
 <listener>
  <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>/index.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

and When I try to have a list with datatable .the managedbean it is not recognized

```
 <p:dataTable id="cars" var="fab" value=***"#{here is not figure*** paginator="true" rows="10"  >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classes which hold spring stereo typed beans (here your backing beans are holding them) should be instanciated via Spring Factories, but backing beans are created by JSF framework. Just use Spring EL Resolvers for JSF to overcome this. He is a relevant [discussion](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?86577-Spring-3-JSF-2) and [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/web-integration.html#jsf-springbeanfaceselresolver)

Also, make sure you have the spring bootstrap configured in the web application context loading via web.xml

```
<!-- Spring Bootstrap -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        package1.where.springbeans.exist
        package2.where.springbeans.exist
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: yeah, that's where you should use the EL resolver. Are you still finding a problem?

Comment: edited my answer to include web context loading based spring bootstrap